# How to do a string shifting in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Assume that the table looks like the following

```
ID  |    Freq0    |     Freq1    | is_overnight | start_time |  end_time  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   _23_5_7   |    _2____7   |       Y      |    1:00    |    3:00    |
2   |   1_____7   |    1______   |       N      |    5:00    |    7:00    |
3   |   _2__5__   |    _2_____   |       N      |    23:00   |    1:00    |
```

where `Freq0` and `Freq1` indicate the occurence of the event `ID`. For example, `Freq0 = 1_____7` means that the event happens on Monday and Sunday. Besides, both `Freq0` and `Freq1` are `varchar(7)`.

The modification logic is if `is_overnight = Y or start_time > end_time`, both `Freq0` and `Freq1` needs to  be right shifted, otherwise there is no change.

The examples of right shift are

```
_23_5_7 => 1_34_6_
1_____7 => 12_____
_2__5__ => __3__6_
```

Applying this logic to the table above, we are supposed to get the following result

```
ID  |    Freq0    |     Freq1    | is_overnight | start_time |  end_time  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   1_34_6_   |    1_3____   |       Y      |    1:00    |    3:00    |
2   |   1_____7   |    1______   |       N      |    5:00    |    7:00    |
3   |   __3__6_   |    __3____   |       N      |    23:00   |    1:00    |
```

I was able to complete this task using `Python` as follows:

```
def right_shift(column_name):
    def helper(raw_data):
        content = raw_data[column_name]
        if raw_data['is_overnight '] == 'Y' or raw_data['start_time '] > raw_data['end_time  ']:
            content = content[-1] + content[:-1]
            content = [str(index + 1)  if content[index] != '_' else '_' for index in range(len(content))]
            return "".join(content)
        else:
            return content
    return helper

raw_data = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connection)
raw_data['Freq0'] = raw_data.apply(right_shift('Freq0'), axis = 1)
raw_data['Freq1'] = raw_data.apply(right_shift('Freq1'), axis = 1)
```

but I was then asked to complete this in sql, which is when I encountered difficulty writing it into a piece of elegant code. Could anyone give me a hand here?

Comment: That is the wrong way to store frequency information. Normalize these frequencies in a separate table.

Comment: @TT. Could you provide more details? Personally, I don't think normalization is a problem here.

Comment: You should probably write a function that will return the newly formatted string. Should be easily done with a simple loop over the characters

Comment: You didn't normalize your information as it should be done in relational databases. So yes, normalization or rather lack of normalization is a problem. You should have the frequencies stored in a separate table, with a row for each day. You'll see that your problem will be easier to solve.

Comment: As far as normalization: You're storing multiple values (the days worked) in a single field.  That's breaking first normal form.  You're also storing repeating columns since you've got both Freq0 and Freq1,  That's also breaking first normal form.  I've certainly worked with less normalized systems, but I'd imagine these fields will be a constant source of difficulty when you get to SQL.

Comment: @TT. Thanks for your suggestion. I usually work on the table sgiven directly without a second consideration of its normalization, which I start to believe is a bad habit. I will start to pay attention to this from now on.

Comment: @ChenChen You are most welcome. There's plenty of good material to find online about relational database design, normalization and things like that. You'll get used to it, that storing things in a relational database is different than storing things in a traditional programming language (containers in Python, Java, C++, ...). The concept of 'array' as a column type doesn't exist in (traditional) relational databases (for good reasons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, not elegant, but seems to work

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Freq0 varchar(7))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('_23_5_7')  -- => 1_34_6_
,('1_____7')  -- => 12_____
,('_2__5__')  -- => __3__6_

Select *
      ,NewVal = concat( IIF(Substring(Freq0,7,1)='_','_','1')
                       ,IIF(Substring(Freq0,1,1)='_','_','2')
                       ,IIF(Substring(Freq0,2,1)='_','_','3')
                       ,IIF(Substring(Freq0,3,1)='_','_','4')
                       ,IIF(Substring(Freq0,4,1)='_','_','5')
                       ,IIF(Substring(Freq0,5,1)='_','_','6')
                       ,IIF(Substring(Freq0,6,1)='_','_','7')
                      )

 From @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
Freq0     NewVal
_23_5_7   1_34_6_
1_____7   12_____
_2__5__   __3__6_
```

Comment: It is not perfect, but at least much cleaner then seven `replace`s and `when`s.